# How to include redundant column to show in SELECT Query from second table instead from the main table in Spring Repository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a query like this:
Query 1:

```
select *
from items item
```

This is bind to an entity in SpringJPA.
Now I have to select one more column from another table like below.

Query 2:

```
select item.*,is.id
from items item
inner join item_state itm_s where item.id=itm_s.id
```

Now,there is a column "code" which exists in both item and item_state. I want to select it from item_state and not from item due to some data issues. I know the straight forward way is to write all columns in select statement,excluding code column from item and including code column from item_state.
But the thing is item table has around 100 columns.
Is there a good way to solve this issue without changing the entity class?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Spring Data JPA projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) and perform the following query:

```
@Query("select item.*, itm_s.code from items item join item.item_state itm_s where item.id = itm_s.id")
```

You will have to look at the resulting query to write your projection class.